# How to initialize a config / run in angularJS after a delay?

Tags: angularjs

My HTML & JS is below.
Can we insert a run / config after a delay in angularJs?

```js
  
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

setTimeout(function(){
  angular.module('plunker').run(function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.$apply(function (){
        $rootScope.hello = "works";

  });

  });
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="demo">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{$root.hello}}
     
  </div>
</section>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help with this. Thank you :)

Comment: I am guessing you are just getting started with Angular now. I'm not sure what resources you are using for this, but 1.2.23 is very, very old.

Comment: Basically I am using  1.5.8 but stackoverflow's editor doesn't have it on them. But that doesn't have anything to do with my question though..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `$timeout` to run a delay.

No need to initialize a new module for this.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.hello = "works";
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="demo">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{hello}}

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No I am not initializing a new module here. I am trying to use the same module. Also the timeout should be wrapped around the script thats because I am inserting this piece of code from the server dynamically.